# How do I escape HTML by default in Liquid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, liquid, html-injections

I know that it's possible to escape HTML in liquid by using the `escape` filter

```
# cthulhu is "<blink>blink</blink>"

{{ cthulhu || escape }}
```

but is it possible to make liquid escape the HTML in all variables by default?

I know that Rails escapes all HTML by default, but I have to use `html_safe` because otherwise all the HTML within the liquid template is escaped.

I only found [this issue](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/149) on GitHub, which told the OP to just ask on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This still seems to be an issue in 2022. There is a ["new" open issue](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/1240) which unfortunately has no answers or solutions.